# how to make instances of event for every single tab on multi tab GUI tkinter( notebook widget)

Tags: python, events, tabs, tkinter

this is my code.. and i need the event binding to work for all tabs the same time..the problem is when generate new tab the event binding will be related to the last generated tab and not working any more for pre-generated tabs..please help--(python 2.7)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import ttk



root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.minsize(300,300)
root.geometry("1000x700")

body=ttk.Notebook(root,width=1000,height=650,)

tabs={'ky':1} 
def generate_tabs(tab,name):

  tab=Tkinter.Frame(body)                            
  entry=Entry(tab).pack(side=TOP)

  def alert(event):
    tkMessageBox.showinfo('alert1','FocusOut event is working for '+name)
  def printing(event):
    print event.keysym+' for '+name


  root.bind("<Key>",printing)

  tab.bind_class('Entry',"<FocusOut>",alert)
  body.add(tab,text=name)

def start_generating():
  if tabs['ky']==4:pass
  elif tabs['ky']==3: generate_tabs('tab4','tab4') ; tabs['ky']=4
  elif tabs['ky']==2: generate_tabs('tab3','tab3') ; tabs['ky']=3
  elif tabs['ky']==1: generate_tabs('tab2','tab2') ; tabs['ky']=2
  else:pass
generate_tabs('tab1','tab1')
button=Button(root,text='generate',command=start_generating).pack(side=LEFT)
body.pack(side=TOP)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Easy there, we all come here voluntarily to help. As for your question, you would likely get a better response if you provided more context and described in more detail what you are trying to achieve. Also, there are some issues with the code you posted. Why is Tkinter imported both as `import Tkinter` and `from Tkinter import *`? Do you realize that the `tab` argument to `generate_tabs()` isn't really used if you re-define `tab` as you do in that functions first line?

Comment: hello there..i think i explained  clearly..if you run the code you will understand what i am trying to achieve..the only thing i want is when selecting one tab and typing or focusing out ;the event must relating to the selected(focused) tab and not to a tab are not selected...this will be clear for you when watching console..

Comment: by the way i changed the first line of generate_tabs function and call the function like this generate_tabs(Tkinter.Frame(body),'tab1')..but still the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use class MyTab to create new tab with own function alert (called when you focus out entry) and printing (called when you type in entry).

I use `print` in place of `tkMessageBox` because messagebox focuse out entry on new selected tab (when you change tab) so you don't see messagebox from previous tab, but from current tab.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import ttk

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
class MyTab(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root, name):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)

        self.root = root
        self.name = name

        self.entry = Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack(side=TOP)

        self.entry.bind('<FocusOut>', self.alert)
        self.entry.bind('<Key>', self.printing)

    #-------------------------------

    def alert(self, event):
        print 'FocusOut event is working for ' + self.name + '  value: ' + self.entry.get()
        #tkMessageBox.showinfo('alert', 'FocusOut event is working for ' + self.name + '  value: ' + self.entry.get())

    #-------------------------------

    def printing(self, event):
        print event.keysym + ' for ' + self.name

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

class Application():

    def __init__(self):

        self.tabs = {'ky':1} 

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.minsize(300, 300)
        self.root.geometry("1000x700")

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.root, width=1000, height=650)

#       self.all_tabs = []

        self.addTab('tab1')

        self.button = Button(self.root, text='generate', command=self.start_generating).pack(side=BOTTOM)

        self.notebook.pack(side=TOP)

    #-------------------------------

    def addTab(self, name):
        tab = MyTab(self.notebook, name)
        self.notebook.add(tab, text=name)
#       self.all_tabs.append(tab)

    #-------------------------------

    def start_generating(self):
        if self.tabs['ky'] < 4:
            self.tabs['ky'] += 1
            self.addTab('tab'+ str(self.tabs['ky'])) 

    #-------------------------------

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

Application().run()
```