# how to toggle event binding on tabs of notebook widget

Tags: python, events, tkinter, ttk

I have a simple application based on tkinter and ttk. I have a notebook widget supposed to create a limited number of tabs and the tabs are the same thing. But I need to do different actions on each one. When I press some button a tab with its own name is created and the event binding will be focus on it. If I select the previous tab that was created with button press, the event binding will not focus on it nor its children widgets and this is the problem I need to solve. Can I toggle event binding between tabs? Any suggestions?
I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 4):

See my answer to question [how to make instances of event for every single tab on multi tab GUI tkinter( notebook widget)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19896049/1832058) to see working example.

I use class `MyTab` to create new tab with own events binding - so I can create many identical tabs and every tab use own events binding. In example tabs show different message when you change tab.

You didn't attache code in your question so I can't add more detailed answer.

**EDIT:**

example from previous link + binding to frame:

- directly in `MyTab` :  `self.bind("<Button-1>", self.clickFrame)` (left mouse call function in `MyTab`
- in `Application` : `tab.bind("<Button-3>", self.clickTab)` (right mouse call function in `Application`

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import ttk

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
class MyTab(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root, name):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)

        self.root = root
        self.name = name

        self.entry = Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack(side=TOP)

        self.entry.bind('<FocusOut>', self.alert)
        self.entry.bind('<Key>', self.printing)

        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.clickFrame)

    #-------------------------------

    def alert(self, event):
        print 'FocusOut event is working for ' + self.name + '  value: ' + self.entry.get()
        #tkMessageBox.showinfo('alert', 'FocusOut event is working for ' + self.name + '  value: ' + self.entry.get())

    #-------------------------------

    def printing(self, event):
        print event.keysym + ' for ' + self.name

    #-------------------------------

    def clickFrame(self, event):
        print "MyTab: click at (" + str(event.x) + ", " + str(event.y) + ') for ' + self.name + " (parent name: " + self.root.tab(CURRENT)['text'] + ")"


#---------------------------------------------------------------------

class Application():

    def __init__(self):

        self.tabs = {'ky':1} 

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.minsize(300, 300)
        self.root.geometry("1000x700")

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.root, width=1000, height=650)

#       self.all_tabs = []

        self.addTab('tab1')

        self.button = Button(self.root, text='generate', command=self.start_generating).pack(side=BOTTOM)

        self.notebook.pack(side=TOP)

    #-------------------------------

    def addTab(self, name):
        tab = MyTab(self.notebook, name)
        tab.bind("<Button-3>", self.clickTab)
        self.notebook.add(tab, text="X-"+name)
#       self.all_tabs.append(tab)

    #-------------------------------

    def clickTab(self, event):
        print "Application: click at (" + str(event.x) + ", " + str(event.y) + ') for ' + event.widget.name

        #-------------------------------

    def start_generating(self):
        if self.tabs['ky'] < 4:
            self.tabs['ky'] += 1
            self.addTab('tab'+ str(self.tabs['ky'])) 

    #-------------------------------

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

Application().run()
```

Comment: ok but the binding in your class is on Entry ..it will not work for frame for example..since tab is a frame ...

Comment: I found solution ...since every tab has tabID we can check to see which tab is selected and then make the binding on it with..easy with IF statement

Comment: You can put your solution as answer - it would be nice if you make simple working example. It can help others. Then We can upvote your answer and you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: by the way: `MyTab` is `Frame` so you can bind directly to that `Frame` inside `MyTab` using `self.bind` or in `Application` using `tab.bind` - see example in my answer. In example you can see also how to get Frame property from event - `event.widget.name`